# What types of XCode provisioning profiles should be created?

Tags: xcode, provisioning, provisioning-profile

After recently joining the Apple Developer Program I am trying to understand the best approach  when creating provisioning profiles.

The fundamental aspect that is not clear is the relationship between the AppID in the provisioning profile and the actual application.

For example, I created the profile

```
MyApp1Profile
```

and successfully installed it in XCode.

However, this profile works in any of my XCode projects/apps and allows me to run the apps on my device.

Is MyApp1Profile supposed to be associated w/ MyApp1 in some way? 
Why does this profile work w/ other apps?
Do you set up different profiles for the same app, e.g., testing and release?

If I am going to be developing multiple apps in different projects does anyone have links to potential best practices on creating profiles?